# Thumb position when driving/rallying

Tags: steering, racing, rally

I am not a rally driver or anything...but out of curiosity, is it safer and more technical to lock my thumbs into the steering wheel when rallying?

If so, then does that apply to normal track racing too?

If not then why shouldn't I lock my thumbs?

(when I'm holding the steering wheel 9 and 3)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get into the habit of not having your thumbs inside the wheel rim ever (racing, off-road, on-road) - a pot-hole or accident can rip the wheel round and break your thumb...

Seen it happen to drivers - off to hospital with a broken thumb for a simple accident, no other injury though...

But this may cause others to say " I was fine"... but do you really want to test?

Comment: Agreed - always keep all your digits on the outside of the wheel!

Comment: Thumbs up for safety! Or non-broken thumbs, whichever...

Comment: so it still would be 9 and 3 but thumbs not locked in the steering right